# Making a Column of Cells Dependent on Eachother in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of dates in a column in Excel and I would like to format this column of cells (say A1 to A10) so that if I change any date in the column then the following dates below will be shifted by the number of days that I added or subtracted from that cell.

I was wondering if there was a way of using Excel's IF function to make this happen?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, I mean using an IF statement for the column of cells.

Comment: What about having length of time an activity would take in column b? So for example, you would have in a1 = 01/01//2017 and in b1 = 2 (as if in 2 days). Then in each proceeding column A cell, you would have a sum. A2 would be `=A1+B1)`. The result in A2 would be 03/07/17. If either a date changes, or the length an activity takes, your entire plan will be updated to reflect it.

Comment: Yes, that could be one way to do it. I assume you meant 03/01/2017? I was thinking that I would use an IF function to change each row in relation to the previous row but that would be a more roundabout way to do it. Thanks for the advice Steven.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have data in column **A** like:

[image]

In **C1** enter:

```
=A1+SUM($B$1:B1)
```

and copy down.  Now all you have to do is enter your **+ / -** values in column **B**.  So if you placed a *4* in cell **B3**, you would get:

[image]

All the dates from **C3** and below would get incremented by *4*.

Comment: I really like this solution. It also means if your dates 'slip' you have a record of it.

Comment: @StevenWalker  I agree...............also no macros............also no array formulas..........

Comment: I would also agree. This is a smart way to do it and I can also keep track of the original due dates. Thank you for suggesting this.